# Data not returned properly from database

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-sqlite

I have this function that returns arraylist of assessments to the user. Every assessment has a arrayList of questions. I get the questions from the database but, when I'm returning the assessment arrayList to the user the questions arrayList is empty. Can anyone help me with populating the questions array.

***Note:***
When I do this `Log.v("--", "Questions: " + questions.size());` from the code bellow it gives me the size ex. 90, but a row after that, when I do 
`Log.v("--", "AssessmentQuestions: "+assessment.getQuestions().size());` it gives me `size: 0`

Here is my code:

```
public ArrayList<Assessment> getAllAsssessments() {
        ArrayList<Assessment> assessments = new ArrayList<Assessment>();
        Assessment assessment;
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TSCYC;
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                int AssessmentID = cursor.getInt(0);
                int childID = cursor.getInt(1);
                int doctorID = cursor.getInt(2);
                String assessmentDate = cursor.getString(3);
                Log.v("--", assessmentDate);
                ArrayList<Question> questions = new ArrayList<Question>();
                Question q;
                assessment = new Assessment(AssessmentID, assessmentDate,
                        doctorID, childID, questions);
                for (int i = 0; i < 90; i++) {
                    q = new Question("i", (i + 1));
                    q.setAnswer(cursor.getInt(i + 4));
                    questions.add(q);
                }
                Log.v("--", "Questions: " + questions.size());
                assessment = new Assessment(AssessmentID, assessmentDate,
                        doctorID, childID, questions);
                assessments.add(assessment);
                Log.v("--", "AssessmentQuestions: "
                        + assessment.getQuestions().size());
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());

        }
        return assessments;
    }
```

The Assessmen class:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Assessment implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1288566422025895376L;
    private String date;
    private int doctorID, childID, id;
    private ArrayList<Question> questions;

    public Assessment(int id, String date, int doctorID, int childID,
            ArrayList<Question> questions) {
        questions = new ArrayList<Question>();
        this.id = id;
        this.setDate(date);
        this.setDoctorID(doctorID);
        this.setChildID(childID);
        this.setQuestions(questions);

    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public int getDoctorID() {
        return doctorID;
    }

    public void setDoctorID(int doctorID) {
        this.doctorID = doctorID;
    }

    public int getChildID() {
        return childID;
    }

    public void setChildID(int childID) {
        this.childID = childID;
    }

    public ArrayList<Question> getQuestions() {
        return questions;
    }

    public void setQuestions(ArrayList<Question> questions) {
        this.questions = questions;
    }

}
```

The Question class:

```
public class Question implements Serializable{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8703113563916355470L;
    private String question;
    private int answer, position;

    public Question(String question, int position) {
        answer = -1;
        this.question = question;
        this.position = position;
    }

    public int getAnswer() {
        return answer;
    }

    public void setAnswer(int answer) {
        this.answer = answer;
    }

    public int getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(int position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public void setQuestion(String question) {
        this.question = question;
    }
}
```

Comment: what does your Assesment constructor look like? sure everything is ok there?

Comment: indeed, do you have anything with a `new` in it in in Assessment, I have a feeling that will be the problem. Regardless we need a complete (short) program to work with

Comment: @RichardTingle can you explain me more in an answer?

Comment: We'll need the code for the Assessment class at a minimum. I know that this has database intergration and so making a self contained example is difficult but we simply don't have enough to work on here

Comment: @RichardTingle code updated and added the classes requested

Comment: @androidika code updated, you can see the assessment class now

Comment: @DarkoPetkovski As I suspected, this is an issue with creating a new Arraylist inside the constructor. See my answer for full details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within your constructor you haven't copied the reference to the questions array list, you've created a new ArrayList, see the marked point in the code below:

```
public Assessment(int id, String date, int doctorID, int childID,
        ArrayList<Question> questions) {
    questions = new ArrayList<Question>(); //<-- here you make a NEW empty ArrayList
    this.id = id;
    this.setDate(date);
    this.setDoctorID(doctorID);
    this.setChildID(childID);
    this.setQuestions(questions); //<-- here you setQuestions as the empty arraylist

}
```

What are you trying to do with the line `questions = new ArrayList<Question>();`, as far as I can see it can simply be omitted.

Comment: @DarkoPetkovski The number of times I've been tripped up by old debug code. Glad I could help!